# Liferay: field missing after Wizard Setup?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, liferay-7.1

A workmate has just set up a local liferay dxp 7.1 instance (hypersonic) and then tried to import a LAR file from another 7.1 instance.

For me it worked (postgres), he's getting an error regarding a missing field:

```
No such field com.liferay.portal.model.impl.GroupImpl._originalName
---- Debugging information ----
message : No such field
com.liferay.portal.model.impl.GroupImpl._originalName
field : _originalName
class : com.liferay.portal.model.impl.GroupImpl
required-type : com.liferay.portal.model.impl.GroupImpl
converter-type : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
path : /StagedGroup/_group/_originalName
line number : 32 class[1] : com.liferay.site.internal.model.adapter.StagedGroupImpl
version : 1.4.10
```

Since tickets are always time consuming I'd like to ask here first wether anyone has any hint regarding the underlying problem...

Comment: LAR import is version dependent - you can only import a LAR that has been created on the same version. If it was created on Liferay CE, and you're importing to DXP, you're out of luck.

Comment: Yes it is. No I haven't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say based on the limited information you've provided.
Here are few things to double-check:

- the LAR file didn't get corrupted while transferred over the wire
- both instances of Liferay DXP are exactly the same (including Service Packs)
- both instances have the same hot-fixes installed
- both instances have the same staging configuration for the imported site
- both instances have the same plug-ins/hooks that customize the import/export behaviour

If those are in place and you still have the issue, open a support ticket.

I don't think this is a DB related issue but to rule that out you can switch your instance to hypersonic and try the import.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check this with my workmate, the hotfix level may not be identical.

Comment: @Gunnar You can try to use the auto upgrade properties or the upgrade tool on the place where the data is produced or downgrade/update the receiver to level both versions. I would not bet on the DB issue either.   Curious about the error message though, _originalName missing...

Comment: Thank you, I'll update here when my workmate applies the patchlevel and tests again, currently he continues working with 7.0

Comment: My workmate imported the LAR successfully after upgrading to an identical Patchlevel (here pack10 a.t.m)